# Type of member 'ReadOnlyCollection`1' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>

Tags: c#, selenium

Есть класс, реализующий page object model, хочу реализовать в нем список элементов.

```
public class SearchPage 
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[@data-gpnav='item']")]
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> GameList { get; set; } 

    public SearchPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

При вызове конструктора в тесте, тест падает с ошибкой.

> System.ArgumentException : Type of member 'ReadOnlyCollection`1' is not IWebElement or IList

Прошу помощи, всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте читать [документацию](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_FindsByAttribute.htm) прежде, чем спрашивать.

> The Type of the field or property must be either `IWebElement` or `IList<IWebElement>`. Any other type will throw an `ArgumentException` when `InitElements(ISearchContext, Object)` is called.

```cs
public IList<IWebElement> GameList { get; set; }
```